# C# Struct Hiding Through Inheritance

Tags: c#, struct

Section **3.7.1.2 Hiding Through Inheritance** of the C# 4 specification discusses the ability for classes or structs to hide members through re-declaring names that were used in base classes.

This is all well and good, but I thought that one of the distinctions of structs was that they could not be inherited.

- **Is this true?**
- **If not, is it still possible to perform member hiding with structs
  in some other way?**
- **Is there anything else to glean from this?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`struct` still inherits from `object`, via `ValueType`. You can `new` (hide) a `GetHashCode`, `Equals` or `ToString` method - however, it would be **incredibly** stupid to do so, as that would mean you can't `override` it, which means it will always be a boxing call to use them (even when done as a *constrained* call).

So, in order:

- is this true: yes, it is true that you cannot inherit from a `struct`
- is it possible: the only thing comparable, other than above, would be explicit interface implementation
- to glean: the specification does not disallow you from doing things that are silly

Comment: Thanks Marc.  I did have in mind the fact that it inherits from Object but dismissed it because I couldn't think of a practical application for hiding those implementations, as you said.  I guess I'll just catalog it in my head a quirk of the language.  Regarding `hiding`, in general, I do like Jesse Liberty's comment about considering the concept as a bug.

Comment: @ChuckT Can you point me to where you read that statement by Jesse Liberty? I'm unable to find it through Google.

Comment: @Virtlink It is in the C# Programming Language Fourth Edition book:  http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/0321741765

Comment: @MarcGravell Can you expound on what you mean when you say "...(even when done as a _constrained_ call)?"

Comment: @ChuckT there are 3 ways of calling a method: "static", "virtual" and "constrained". Constrained applies to *instance* methods, and most simply means "I don't know", and is used most commonly (but not exclusively) by *generics* - the JIT looks at the method: if it is a class it does a virtual call; if it is a struct that *overrides* the method it does a static call; if it is a struct that *does not override* the method, it does a box + virtual call. Very convenient.